# Docker Containers Cannot Access the Internet

Tags: docker

I am having a variety of issues with my Docker containers running on a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.  After lengthy troubleshooting, I believe (but am not necessarily sure) that the issue is related to internet connectivity from within the Docker container.  Below is a series of stripped-down steps I can take that I believe should work, but do not work, that I believe exemplify the issue on my VPS.

```
docker run -it alpine
```

This command successfully runs and starts the container.

From within the container:

```
apk update
```

This is where the failure occurs.  The result I get is:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main: temporary error (try again later)
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community: temporary error (try again later)
4 unavailable, 0 stale; 15 distinct packages available
```

I have been troubleshooting this for days with no avail.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

From outside of the container, I am able to ping dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org as expected.

From outside of the container, I am able to curl https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz as expected.

*From inside the container*, /etc/resolv.conf is, which looks correct to me:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 172.26.0.2
search us-east-2.compute.internal
```

I do not believe I am behind a proxy, but do not know of a way to positively verify this.

From outside the container, sudo iptables -L returns the following, which I believe looks rights.  I do not believe there are any additional firewalls, but I do not know of a way to positively verify this.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

docker network inspect bridge

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "92d96247979cc2db1b6b25f471a8c9f7761104ef5e1a69d14eb982032b6b5d65",
        "Created": "2024-02-15T17:47:46.223814476Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "c52c39b0836d766002f39909a3745cd84e442650d3ab2d439bdc9d3bce834f36": {
                "Name": "suspicious_cannon",
                "EndpointID": "3bc35e264a77081eb701885ed8d7f1ed917136b163a07ddcebd3abd865120385",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: One step at a time. Can you access dns from inside container? Can you ping you host ip from inside container? Can you ping docker bridge ip from inside container? While you try to ping, what is the output of tcpdump listening on the bridge? Try tcpdump everywhere and see where it stops?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for the response.  I am able to ping the host IP address from the container (the ip address that returns from nslookup hostname outside of the container).  However, I am not able to ping the IP address of the gateway of the bridge network inside the container.  Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting, it was rebooting systemd that fixed this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).